# boot hang on random: crng init dome

Tags: boot, kernel, debian

I have kernel [4.9.80](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) (arm64) installed on a Debian stable system. This is on a RPI 3b. When the kernel gets to the line `random: crng init done`, it stops and never continues. I have read other articles on the issue, but none had a definitive answer. I can try whatever to get it booting.

Comment: You didn't tell which kernel configuration and compiler you have used. But even if you did, I frankly wouldn't expect that someone here will be willing to debug that for you.

Comment: the bcmrpi3_defconfig target and aarch64-linux-gnu for compiling the kernel. It's gcc 6.3

Comment: `random. crng init done` was earlier started and runs some time, even when other services already stopped. That is parallel execution of `systemd`. Therefore the message is mostly the last one but less relevant. Look at the messages just before and have in mind they are not executed in sequence.

Comment: Unfortunetnly this is only 2 seconds into boot and there is no other error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: press enter and the prompt shows up.